# Temporarily replace a variable for an include

Tags: ansible

I have a task like this:

```
- include: tasks/install_nginx_vhost.yml
  vars:
    domain_name: learn.{{ domain_name }}

- include: tasks/install_nginx_vhost.yml
  vars:
    domain_name: author.{{ domain_name }}
```

But I am getting this error:

```
recursive loop detected in template string
```

Is it possible to temporarily (only for the include) override a variable like this? Because I don't want to create additional variables.

Comment: PS: Can't help but mention that it's clearly stupidity on ansible's part of report such an error given that it only makes one pass in evaluating expressions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29276198/ansible-how-to-construct-a-variable-from-another-variable-and-then-fetch-its-v/29280622#29280622

Answer (score 2):

Not really.

```
- set_fact:
    learn_domain_name:  "learn.{{ domain_name }}"
    author_domain_name: "author.{{ domain_name }}"

- include: tasks/install_nginx_vhost.yml
  vars:
    domain_name: "{{ learn_domain_name }}"

- include: tasks/install_nginx_vhost.yml
  vars:
    domain_name: "{{ author_domain_name }}"
```

or more advisable, if possible, would be you rename the original `domain_name` say to `domain_name_suffix`. Then:

```
- include: tasks/install_nginx_vhost.yml
  vars:
    domain_name: learn.{{ domain_name_suffix }}

- include: tasks/install_nginx_vhost.yml
  vars:
    domain_name: author.{{ domain_name_suffix }}
```