# ansible include with array slices

Tags: amazon-s3, ansible

In Ansible 2.2, I want to loop over a large list of files read from S3.

Here is my `role/tasks/main.yml`

```
  - name: Simulate variable read from S3
    set_fact:
      list_of_files_to_import: [
        "a.tar.gz",
        "b.tar.gz",
        "c.tar.gz",
        "d.tar.gz",
        "e.tar.gz",
        "f.tar.gz",
        "g.tar.gz",
        "h.tar.gz",
        ...
        "zz.tar.gz"
      ]

  - name: Process each file from S3
    include: submodule.yml
    with_items: list_of_files_to_import
```

Here is `role/tasks/submodule.yml`

```
---
  - name: Restore TABLE {{ item }}
    debug: var={{ item }}
```

This crashes because there are too many files.

I have found that I can slice the array and send sections at a time:

```
  - name: Process each file from S3
    include: submodule.yml
    with_items: "{{ list_of_files_to_import[0:5] }}"

  - name: Process each file from S3
    include: submodule.yml
    with_items: "{{ list_of_files_to_import[5:10] }}"

  - name: Process each file from S3
    include: submodule.yml
    with_items: "{{ list_of_files_to_import[10:15] }}"

  - name: Process each file from S3
    include: submodule.yml
    with_items: "{{ list_of_files_to_import[15:20] }}"
```

Instead of hardcoding all these little blocks, I wanted to try something like

```
  - name: Process each file from S3
    include: submodule.yml
    with_items: "{{ list_of_files_to_import[{{start}}:{{end}}] }}"
```

But we [cannot get variable-defined variable names](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29280622/194309)

How can I process a large list of items in Ansible 2.2?

Comment: How large is the list? And what is the reason of crash? Too many includes?

Comment: It is on the order of 300 files.  The only reason I see is "out of memory."  But yes, it seems like it cannot handle so many includes.

Comment: I'm not sure on your details, but it kinda looks like issue [#16391](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/16391). If that's the case the issue should be fixed on the next Ansible release.

Comment: @Doomy you may be right.  I ended up solving it with Bash.  I'll post my solution.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up solving it with a shell script, repeatedly calling the playbook with some `--extra-vars` to specify which files to process.

This only works because the list of files in S3 have similar filenames.  Basically it loops through the filenames and processes each one at a time.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# return 0(true) if the year/month combination is valid
valid() {
   yr=$1
   mn=$2
   # do not run on months after this month
   if [ "$yr" -eq "2017" -a "$mn" -gt "$(date +%m)" ]
   then
     return 1
   fi

   return 0
}

# For every year from 2002 to this year
for year in `seq 2002 $(date +%Y)`
do
   # for every zero-padded month, 01-12
   for month in `seq -f "%02g" 01 12`
   do
      # for each type of item in inventory
      for object in widgets doodads
      do
          if valid $year $month;
          then
             ansible-playbook playbook_name.yml --extra-vars "object=$object year=$year month=$month"
          else
             echo skipping invalid combo $object $year $month
          fi
      done
   done
done
```