# Ansible include_vars into dictionary

Tags: dictionary, ansible, yaml

In my ansible playbook, I read a list of directories into a list. I then want to read a "config.yml" file from each of these directories and put their content into dictionary, so that I can reference the config-data via the directory name from that dictionary.
The first part is no problem, but I cannot get the second part to work:

Step 1, load directories:

```
- name: Include directories
  include_vars:
  file: /main-config.yml
  name: config
```

Step 2, load configs from directories:

```
- name: load deploymentset configurations
  include_vars:
    file: /path/{{ item }}/config.yml
    name: "allconfs.{{ item }}"   ## << This is the problematic part 
  with_items:
    - "{{ config.dirs }}"
```

I tried different things like `"allconfs['{{ item }}']`, but none seemed to work. The playbook completed successfully, but the data was not in the dictionary.
I also tried defining the outer dictionary beforehand, but that did not work either.

The config files themselves are very simple:

/main-config.yml:

```
dirs:
- dir1
- dir2
- dir3
```

/path/dir1/config.yml:

```
some_var: "some_val"
another_var: "another val"
```

I want to be able to then access the values of the config.yml files like this:

`{{ allconfs.dir1.some_var }}`

***UPDATE*** to try Konstantins approach:

```
  - name: load deploymentset configurations
    include_vars:
      file: /repo/deploymentsets/{{ item }}/config.yml
      name: "default_config"
    with_items:
    - "{{ config.deploymentsets }}"
    register: default_configs


  - name: combine configs
    set_fact:
      default_configs: "{{ dict(default_configs.results | json_query('[].[item, ansible_facts.default_config]')) }}"
```

Error message:

`fatal: [127.0.0.1]: FAILED! => {"failed": true, "msg": "Unexpected templating type error occurred on ({{ dict(default_configs.results | json_query('[].[item, ansible_facts.default_config]')) }}): <lambda>() takes exactly 0 arguments (1 given)"}`

Comment: Can you include examples of `/main-config.yml` and `/path/{{ item }}/config.yml`?

Comment: Please ellaborate on the downvote, as the question is precise, includes all relevant code and is not a duplicate.

Answer (score 5):

Here is a piece of code from one of my projects with similar functionality:

```
- name: Load config defaults
  include_vars:
    file: "{{ item }}.yml"
    name: "default_config"
  with_items: "{{ config_files }}"
  register: default_configs
  tags:
    - configuration

- name: Combine configs into one dict
  # Здесь мы делаем словарь вида
  # default_configs:
  #   config_name_1: { default_config_object }
  #   config_name_2: { default_config_object }
  #   config_name_3: { default_config_object }
  #   ...
  set_fact:
    default_configs: "{{ dict(default_configs.results | json_query('[].[item, ansible_facts.default_config]')) }}"
  tags:
    - configuration
```

`default_config` is a dummy var to temporary load var data.
The trick is to use `register: default_configs` with `include_vars` and parse it with the following task stripping out unnecessary fields.

Comment: Looks promising, but I get `Unexpected templating type error occurred on ({{ dict(conf_reg.results | json_query('[].[item, ansible_facts.default_config]')) }}): <lambda>() takes exactly 0 arguments (1 given)"`
Can you show example of one of your config files?

Comment: It's arbitrary YAML files. I see you replaced `default_configs` to `conf_reg`, if you had also replaced `default_config` dummy, update json query accordingly.

Comment: I reverted to your names, but I still get the error. I posted my exact code above

Comment: here is a working example: https://gist.github.com/berlic/bedf6024ca9aa327ae15f65412c37668. what ansible version are you on?

Comment: Indeed the error was fixed for me by upgrading the jinja2 library, which was still at 2.7: `pip install jinja2 --upgrade`

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK it isn't possible to create a single dictionary that encompasses multiple `include_vars`.  From my testing it would create separate dictionaries for each included directory.  Here's what you can do instead.

Remove `allconfs.` from your variable name.

```
- name: load deploymentset configurations
  include_vars:
    file: /path/{{ item }}/config.yml
    name: "{{ item }}"
  with_items:
    - "{{ config.dirs }}"
```

You can then either access variables directly with

```
debug:
  msg: "{{ dir1.some_var }}"
with_items: "{{ config.dirs }}"
```

Or if you need to loop through all variables in your included directories use this (hoisted from [Ansible: how to construct a variable from another variable and then fetch it's value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29276198/ansible-how-to-construct-a-variable-from-another-variable-and-then-fetch-its-v)).

```
debug:
  msg: "{{ hostvars[inventory_hostname][item].some_var }}"
with_items: "{{ config.dirs }}"
```