# In ansible how to initialise a variable from another variable?

Tags: variables, ansible, ansible-role

In an Ansible role, how to define a variable depending on another one?

I am designing a role and want its interface to understand a playbook variable like `framework_enable_java = yes` or `framework_enable_java = mysql tomcat` and want to write a `vars/main.yml` files that defines boolean values

```
framework_enable_java_core
framework_enable_java_mysql
framework_enable_java_tomcat
```

according to the content of `framework_enable_java`. I tried the obvious definitions similar to

```
framework_enable_java_mysql: 'mysql' in framework_enable_java
```

and several more or less subtle approaches like

```
framework_enable_java_mysql: {{ 'mysql' in framework_enable_java }}
```

or

```
{% if 'mysql' in framework_enable_java %}
framework_enable_java_mysql: yes
{% else %}
framework_enable_java_mysql: no
{% endif %}
```

None of them turned out to be working.  The [similar looking question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29276198/ansible-how-to-construct-a-variable-from-another-variable-and-then-fetch-its-v) is unrelated as it is more like implementing variable indirection than variable deduction.

Is it at all possible to write the desired  `vars/main.yml` for my role? How would it look like?  If it is not possible, what would be the best way to make these deductions? (*e.g.* using a task include?)

Comment: What is the problem with `framework_enable_java_mysql: "{{ 'mysql' in framework_enable_java }}"` apart from missing quotes?

Comment: @KonstantinSuvorov With quotes, it works fine. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer from the comments:

```
framework_enable_java_mysql: "{{ 'mysql' in framework_enable_java }}"
```

Double quotes are essential here because otherwise YAML parser tries to construct an object(dictionary) and not templated variable.